# Loading a JS code after a page loads

Tags: javascript, php

I have an advertisement JS code installed on my forum, and I want it to be loaded after the forum has been fully loaded, How to do that?

This is the JS code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://adv.sitemarketing.sa/components/com_adagency/ad_agency_zone.php?zid=261"></script>
```

I have five of them.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 1):

Just add the JS at the bottom close to `</body>`.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://adv.sitemarketing.sa/components/com_adagency/ad_agency_zone.php?zid=261"></script>
```

This is the way [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) loads js.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add script after page is loaded:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function downloadJS() {
  var element = document.createElement("script");
    element.src = "http://adv.sitemarketing.sa/components/com_adagency/ad_agency_zone.php?zid=261";
  document.body.appendChild(element);
}
if (window.addEventListener) {
  window.addEventListener("load", downloadJS, false);
} else if (window.attachEvent) {
  window.attachEvent("onload", downloadJS);
} else window.onload = downloadJS;
</script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the script did not work..
I really appreciate your help.

Comment: thats strange, anyway, the basic idea is that you create a script element and attach it to the DOM tree on `window.onload` event handler